# Pulling Random Quotes in VBA

Tags: vba

Hi I'm pulling random quotes from three arrays and piecing them together in a label. My code is below. How do I get it to recognize and pull from the zero array. Right now with my random number part of the code I believe that it ignores the first array item from each group. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Declare the first array and how many items it will hold
        Dim firstBS_Group(13) As String
        firstBS_Group(0) = "24/7"
        firstBS_Group(1) = "multi-Tier"
        firstBS_Group(2) = "30,000 foot"
        firstBS_Group(3) = "B-B"
        firstBS_Group(4) = "smart"
        firstBS_Group(5) = "six-sigma"
        firstBS_Group(6) = "critical-path"
        firstBS_Group(7) = "dynamic"
        firstBS_Group(8) = "leveraged"
        firstBS_Group(9) = "aligned"
        firstBS_Group(10) = "targeted"
        firstBS_Group(11) = "shared"
        firstBS_Group(12) = "cooperative"


        'Declare the second array and how many items it will hold
        Dim secondBS_Group(13) As String
        secondBS_Group(0) = "empowered"
        secondBS_Group(1) = "sticky"
        secondBS_Group(2) = "value-added"
        secondBS_Group(3) = "oriented"
        secondBS_Group(4) = "centric"
        secondBS_Group(5) = "distributed"
        secondBS_Group(6) = "clustered"
        secondBS_Group(7) = "branded"
        secondBS_Group(8) = "outside-the-box"
        secondBS_Group(9) = "positioned"
        secondBS_Group(10) = "networked"
        secondBS_Group(11) = "focused"
        secondBS_Group(12) = "accelerated"

        'Declare the third array and how many items it will hold
        Dim thirdBS_Group(12) As String
        thirdBS_Group(0) = "process"
        thirdBS_Group(1) = "tipping-point"
        thirdBS_Group(2) = "solution"
        thirdBS_Group(3) = "architecture"
        thirdBS_Group(4) = "core-competency"
        thirdBS_Group(5) = "strategy"
        thirdBS_Group(6) = "mindshare"
        thirdBS_Group(7) = "portal"
        thirdBS_Group(8) = "space"
        thirdBS_Group(9) = "vision"
        thirdBS_Group(10) = "paradigm"
        thirdBS_Group(11) = "mission"

        Label1.Text = firstBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 12)) + " " + secondBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 12)) + " " + thirdBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 11))

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your asuumption that the number generator does not include zero array , I have changed the number generator algorithm which includes the zero array

Change your final line

> Label1.Text = firstBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 12)) + " " +
>   secondBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 12)) + " " + thirdBS_Group(Int(Rnd() * 11))

To

> firstBS_Group(Int ((11 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)) + " " + secondBS_Group(Int
>   ((11 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)) + " " + thirdBS_Group(Int ((10 - 0 + 1) *
>   Rnd + 0))

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect job for RandBetween().

Change the end of your code to:

```
firstBS_Group(worksheetfunction.RandBetween(0,13)) & " " & _
secondBS_Group(worksheetfunction.RandBetween(0,13)) & " " & _ 
thirdBS_Group(worksheetfunction.RandBetween(0,12))
```

Note the use of the "&" symbol in the code. Which is the VBA way to concatenate text. The plus symbol is for math and can bite you sometimes.